# Creating list item from outlook mail

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, csom

I have a requirement where I have to update list item in a list fetching values from an e-mail.
I have to create a button in the outlook ribbon, clicking on which the values (in key-value pair) should be stored in the sharepoint 2013 list.
Cannot use server side coding. It has to be done by client side.

Comment: What do you mean by button in outlook ribbon? explain please

Comment: you can use an email address where you can send email and it will go to the list after some configuration. Is this what you want?

Comment: First, I want to create a button on outlook ribbon, something like save in sharepoint list. I am planning to do it via Office Add-Ins --> Outlook Add-In.
Second, on that button click, it should read the email (which will be received in key-value pair) and update it on sharepoint list.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Outlook Add-In with Visual Studio (C#). Then add SharePoint Client References and CSOM Code to your Add-In Project.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class CreateListItem
    {
        static void Main()
        {   
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
            oListItem["Body"] = "Hello World!";

            oListItem.Update();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

References

Outlook Addin:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

CSOM Create List Item

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx